# VB.NET Continuously Adding One to a Text Box

Tags: vb.net, exception, overloading

I am trying to create a program that has a button and a text box. Everytime the button is pushed I want it to add one to the text box. I keep getting this error:

> Overload resolution failed because no
>   accessible 'Int' accepts this number
>   of arguments

Also I am a huge n00b. Here is where I am at so far, thanks in advance.

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

  Private Sub btnPlus_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPlus.Click
    Dim i As Integer = Int.Parse(txtAdd.Text)
    i += 1
    txtAdd.Text = i.ToString()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the TryParse method will mean that the code does not throw a Format exception if the input cannot be parsed to an integer

```
Private Sub btnPlus_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim i as Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(txtAdd.Text, i) Then
        i += 1
        txtAdd.Text = i.ToString()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This doesnt crash the program but it doesn't add one to the text box. Im not familiar with Int32, what does it do?

Comment: Int32 is the .NET type for the VB.NET Integer type (or the C# int type). In your language of choice, it is interchangable with the native type.

Comment: I've updated my answer to better show the example. Try it with a random text string, then try it with an integer... then try your original code in the same way :)

Comment: This has been a great help. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim i As Integer = Int32.Parse(txtAdd.Text)
```

or

```
Dim i As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtAdd.Text)
```

There's no class called "Int."

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you meant to do:
`Integer.Parse(txtAdd.Text)`

Also, I'd suggest making `Integer i` a member variable (field) of Form1.   That way you wouldn't have to Parse it from string to int.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim i As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        i += 1
        Me.TextBox1.Text = i.ToString()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Calling Convert.ToInt32(txtAdd.Text)

```
Dim i As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(txtAdd.Text)
```